# How to show id with exactly three different cases in M:m table SQL

Tags: sql

Im looking for a soulutin to this problem, where this would be the table:

| ID | cars |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | volvo |
| 1 | volvo |
| 1 | Benz |
| 2 | toyota |
| 2 | Benz |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | volvo |
| 3 | Benz |

and the outcome would be like this

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |

because ID:2 is the only one that has exactly 3 different cars, but others don´t.
how is this posible, and how is it in general?

Comment: What is the query you have so far? Please, provide some code you've tried. Tip: you need `count(distinct ...)` and `having` clause.

Comment: Thank you, I already got the perfect answer, so I won't update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(distinct cars) = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to convert it to my other project